# Launching web inspector on startup in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-inspector

I'm trying to profile an extensions on startup of chrome. It has to be done using console.profile, but it doesn't do anything until the web inspector is opened.

So I wonder if there are some way to launch chrome with the web inspector open, or some way to get a remote debugger to attach quick enough so that console.profile will be triggered on startup?

It would be nice if there was a console. method to launch the web inspector, a way of attaching remotely or the best would probably be a command line option, but I have not seen any.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/sokolovstas/SublimeWebInspector

Comment: Since you are connecting from the debugger to the debugged, it will probably not be able to connect early enough?